# Muttator moveto not moving to parent folder

Tags: thunderbird, addons

Using Muttator 3.1 and Thunderbird 24.5, I try to move a message to a folder that has subfolders.

*moveto Account: Account/Inbox/Orders/*

This results in the error:

More than one match for /Account/Inbox/Orders/

Is there a more correct command or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Although I'm now using kmail, I found these instructions for a problem with vimperator ('gi' command breaking): 

https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/33

`cd **SOMEWHERE**
git clone https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/
cd vimperator-labs
git checkout 3.8.3-a3
make
# to install the created `xpi` file into your firefox type the below into its `command line`
:open file:///**SOMEWHERE**/vimperator-labs/downloads/vimperator-3.8.3.xp`

The difference that I used 3.8.3-a5.  This generated XPIs for both vimperator and muttator.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The muttator's commit https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/commit/c597b0afbc487ec9c0b4598042ca0a6602a22771 seems to solve this problem.

Unfortunately, the latest release available to be installed is 1.2. To use this functionality, you must make the plugin by your self.

It is easy as pie, I just clone the vimperator repo and run make in the muttator folder. This leads me to a xpi file to be installed in thunderbird.